# Нужно ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"...предпочитает справляться собственными силами — чего бы это ему ни стоило" — разве тут должно быть тире?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По моему мнению, здесь постановка тире факультативна (вместо него может быть запятая). В любом случае ошибки нет. Тире здесь служит для усиления интонации.

Answer (score 0):

Всегда для корректной правки лучше предлагать полное предложение. Тире здесь как авторский знак, конечно, может стоять. Но вот запятую я бы **не** поставила, **так ка**к придаточное предложение представляет собой **устойчивое сочетание.**